# HeaderValueException: Unable to parse "Accept-Language" header value es-419

Tags: java, jersey

I've been getting the following error happening when a user has an "Accept-Language: es-419" set in chrome.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be fixed by

- [Upgrading Jersey](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2124), or
- If you're app is running under an Apache Load Balancer, use `mod_headers` to rewrite the header, and avoid this problem like so:

  ```
   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
     RequestHeader edit Accept-Language "es-419" "es-ES"
   </IfModule>
  ```